Apply an equation based on two sets with different indexes
Apply an equation based on two sets with different indexes
Simple example
If I have the following elements in the form of two sets with different indexes:
$m=\{m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5\}=\{1,2,2,2,1\}$
$p=\{p_1=\{a_1,a_2\},p_2=\{a_3\},p_3=\{a_4,a_5\}\}$
c = {Subscript[m, 1], Subscript[m, 2], Subscript[m, 3], Subscript[m, 
   4], Subscript[m, 5]} == {1, 2, 2, 2, 1}
P = {Subscript[p, 1] = {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}, 
   Subscript[p, 1] = {Subscript[a, 2]}, 
   Subscript[p, 3] = {Subscript[a, 4], Subscript[a, 5]}};
Subscript[l, j] = 
 Min[Subscript[a, i] = Subscript[m, i], 
  Subscript[a, i] \[Element] Subscript[p, j]]

Where $a_i$, $m_i$, $i=1,2,...,5$ and $p_j,l_j$, $j=1,2,3$
I want to apply the following equation that depends on the index of the element
$$l_j=\min \left(a_i=m_i,a_i\in p_j\right)$$
I have to get these results: $l_1=1,l_2=2$ and $l_3=1$
How can this equation be generalized, no matter how many inputs increase?
A more general example
$m=\{m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5,m_6,m_7,m_8\}=\{1,3,2,0,2,1,4,2\}$
$p=\{p_1=\{a_1,a_2\},p_2=\{a_3,a_5\},p_3=\{a_4,a_6\},p_4=\{a_7,a_8\},p_5=\{a_1,a_2,a_8\},p_6=\{a_1,a_3,a_6\}\}$
How can this equation be applied in general, regardless of the number of elements in the two sets?
My attempts

How can $l_i$ be named automatically, i.e. $l_1,l_2,...$
Please help with respect

Are you going to give larger input data with = as the source code above? I advise you to use Rule or Association instead. If you insist on using =, then it is better to use a[1], a[2],... with Format[a[i_]]:=Subscript[a,i].

Modify the values ​​of mLength, pLength and the lists following (**) as needed when using.
mLength = 8;
M = Array[m, mLength];
MapThread[Set,(**){M, {1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2}}];
pLength = 6;
pa =(**){{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {7, 8}, {1, 2, 8}, {1, 3, 6}};
P = Array[p, pLength];
MapThread[Set, {P, Map[a, pa, {2}]}];
TableForm[Min /@ P /. a[i_] -> m[i], 
 TableHeadings -> {"l" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[1, pLength], None}]

